# ios 7 simulator is just a screen, no phone

Tags: xcode5, ios-simulator, ios7.1

I am trying to create my screenshots of my app for the walkthrough and the app store. Instead of just having plain screenshots of just the screen, I want the screen to be in an actual iPhone 5s. I was going to use grab, but my simulator is only a screen now, no bezel or anything. I remember in previous versions of xcode, the simulator was an actual iPhone and I am wondering if there is any way I can get that back (with iPhone 5s preferably but iPhone 5 would work). I know it is possible because I have seen it in the app store I just can't figure out how. Thanks for help.

[image: Here is a screen shot of my current iPhone Retina (4-inch 64-bit) for ios7.1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Software like **Photoshop** does the job. Use an **Iphone PSD** and **add** your app's screen shot layer on it. There is no other way.

**e.g iPhone psd:**

http://www.teehanlax.com/tools/iphone/

**Screen shots for app store tutorial:**

http://www.bluecloudsolutions.com/blog/awesome-screen-shots-app-store/

Comment: that looks great. do you know of any iPhone 5s templates?

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing cmd + 1, cmd + 2 or cmd + 3 to see if you get the iPhone's frame. I've seen that it depends on the resolution of your display. On the Retina MBP, I get the frame, but on an external display I get only the screen.